# Keras. How to concatenate intermediate layers of two different models into a third model

Tags: keras

I have two sequential models that both do a pretty good job of classifying audio. One uses mfccs and the other wave forms. I am now trying to combine them into a third functional API model using one of the later Dense layers from each of the mfcc and wave form models. The example about how to get the intermediate layers in the Keras FAQ is not working for me (https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer).

Here is my code:

```
mfcc_model = load_model(S01_model_local_loc)
waveform_model = load_model(T01_model_local_loc)

mfcc_input = Input(shape=(79,30,1))
mfcc_model_as_layer = Model(inputs=mfcc_model.input,
                                 outputs=mfcc_model.get_layer(name = 'dense_9').output)

waveform_input = Input(shape=(40000,1))
waveform_model_as_layer = Model(inputs=waveform_model.input,
                                 outputs=waveform_model.get_layer(name = 'dense_2').output)

concatenated_1024 = concatenate([mfcc_model_as_layer, waveform_model_as_layer])

model_pred = layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated_1024)
uber_model = Model(inputs=[mfcc_input,waveform_input], outputs=model_pred)
```

This throws the error:

*AttributeError: Layer sequential_5 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the notion of "layer input" is ill-defined. Use `get_input_at(node_index)` instead.*

Changing the inputs to the first two Model statements to `inputs=mfcc_model.get_input_at(1)` and `inputs=waveform_model.get_input_at(1)` solves that error message, but I then get this error message:

*ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("dropout_21_input:0", shape=(?, 79, 30, 1), dtype=float32) at layer "dropout_21_input". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []*

If I remove the .get_layer statements and just take the final output of the model the graph connects nicely.

What do I need to do to just get the output of the Dense layers that I want?

---

Update: I found a really hacky way of getting what I want. I pop'ed off the layers of the mfcc and wave form models until the output layers were what I wanted. Then the code below seems to work. I'd love to know the right way to do this!

```
mfcc_input = Input(shape=(79,30,1))
waveform_input = Input(shape=(40000,1))

mfcc_model_as_layer = mfcc_model(mfcc_input)
waveform_model_as_layer = waveform_model(waveform_input)

concatenated_1024 = concatenate([mfcc_model_as_layer, waveform_model_as_layer])

model_pred = layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(concatenated_1024)
test_model = Model(inputs=[mfcc_input,waveform_input], outputs=model_pred)
```

Comment: Could be wrong here but might be your final dense layer, with 2 nodes. If I recall correctly, for a binary problem this should be 1. I.e. it's either a 1 or nothing (0)

Comment: That is not it. All of my models run successfully with that final dense configuration. My issue is more likely to be how I am extracting the Dense layers from the mfcc and waveform models.